# why console.log is called only one time in a recursive query?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, graphql-js

Hello I have an graphQL api and in one resolver I return and author object, this object has post and post has author again, and bassicaly the api has the following resolver

```
getAuthors() => {
    console.log('getAuthors')
    return authors
}
```

But when I call to the api with the following query

```
getAuthors {
    post{
        authors{
           post{
               authors{
                   post{
                       authors{
                           post{
                               authors{
                                   post{ content }
                               }

                            }

                        }
                   }
              }
          }
```

Why only print one time, how works the resolver in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Your query uses `post` and `authors` repeatedly, but it only uses `getAuthors` once. Why do you expect that to run many times?

Comment: then If authors is a sql query, then only is execute one time, and proceses the recursivity?, is this recursivity process in the client or in the server? thx

Comment: you're thinking about field/prop resolver (`post.authors`, `authors.post`) ... if exists - probably not, type resolver probably returns whole post or authors object ... de facto you're only using log onla at [top level] query resolver (`getAuthors`)